# Execute a function each time mysql_query is called. (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache

I've inherited some code which uses raw "mysql_query". No wrapper or anything.
I want to get a log of every query sent to MySQL and the server guy has gone home, so I can't ask him to turn query logging on for a moment.

Is there any way of doing this?

Cheers.

Comment: You can search for `mysql_query` on all of the files that you inherited and replace them to use a wrapper can't you? In `eclipse` you can even `search and replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- install [mysql_proxy](https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy) somewhere,
- configure [it with a LUA script to log all statements](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/databases/2007/07/12/getting-started-with-mysql-proxy.html).
- connect the proxy to the real server
- connect your application to the proxy (database connection settings)

Comment: Interesting, but not possible, sadly. I can't install things.

Comment: @Muu: you could install it on you own computer (or at least something with a public IP address). Does not need to be local to the MySQl server or the PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

run:

```
mysql_query('SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;');
```

Comment: if you don't have access to log file then only option is to wrap out the mysql_query. but you need to factorize everything. just wait your server guy

Comment: I know, usually we use wrappers or the Zend Framework but for some reason this site did not. No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it with `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';`

Comment: I don't have access to the log files - am I right in saying that would just start logging to the file specified in config?

Comment: yes it would. you'll probably need to write a wrapper for mysql and use that to do the queries so that you can log it with PHP. You should be able to use find/replace to implement it quickly, but make sure you backup or use SVN or something just in case

Comment: Usually our sites are written in Zend and even if not, we use a wrapper. The person who wrote this site wasn't too database-friendly (read: a product listing page generating 2000 queries). That's why I'm currently working on it.